# Can I omit part of a compound word when it's repeated?

Tags: hyphenation, lists

Is it correct to omit *term* in the following sentence? Or must I repeat it like in sentence 2?

> 1. The short- and long-term projections are completed.
> 2. The short-term and long-term projections are completed.

Comment: I reckon this is a duplicate of [Can a hyphen be used without anything on the right side?](/q/39860), but it appears both answers here disagree.

Comment: @AndrewL - I like the answer over there better than either of the answers here. Moreover, I appreciate how the answer over there at least cites a style manual.

Comment: Few, any, seem to have understood the question. **Don't** hasten to down vote.

Comment: It's NOT a duplicate of the referenced post.

Answer (score -1):

Naturally, one would use the noun phrase:

> the **short-term** and **long-term** projections,

*short-term* and *long-term* being adjectives modifying *projections*.

Answer (score -2):

I would phrase it as

> The short and long-term projections are completed.

The assumption in the phrasing makes the dash after short is implied in the same way that the -term is implied.

Comment: This is wrong. This implies that the projections are both long-term and short (as opposed to short-term).